# How to make Razor Page with HTML inputs shorter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm working on a app where you can make an appointment. My goal is to make view with 2 weeks ahead, each day with 12 inputs. How can i make it without declaring lots of variables?

```
@{
        IEnumerable<Reservation> ListOfDates = ViewData["ListOfDates"] as IEnumerable<Reservation>;


        TimeSpan ts1 = new TimeSpan(10, 00, 0);
        TimeSpan ts2 = new TimeSpan(10, 30, 0);
        TimeSpan ts3 = new TimeSpan(11, 00, 0);
        TimeSpan ts4 = new TimeSpan(11, 30, 0);
        TimeSpan ts5 = new TimeSpan(12, 00, 0);

        DateTime date1 = DateTime.Now.Date + ts1;

        DateTime date2 = DateTime.Now.Date + ts2;

        DateTime date3 = DateTime.Now.Date + ts3;

        DateTime date4 = DateTime.Now.Date + ts4;

        DateTime date5 = DateTime.Now.Date + ts5;

    }

<form asp-action="CreateRes">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <span asp-validation-for="ServiceDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <a>@date1.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy")</a><br />


                    <label asp-for="ServiceDate">@date1.TimeOfDay</label>
                    <input asp-for="ServiceDate" type="radio" id="dat1" value="@date1"><br>
                    <label asp-for="ServiceDate">@date2.TimeOfDay</label>
                    <input asp-for="ServiceDate" type="radio" id="dat2" value="@date2"><br>
                    <label asp-for="ServiceDate">@date3.TimeOfDay</label>
                    <input asp-for="ServiceDate" type="radio" id="dat3" value="@date3"><br>
                    <label asp-for="ServiceDate">@date4.TimeOfDay</label>
                    <input asp-for="ServiceDate" type="radio" id="dat4" value="@date4"><br>
                    <label asp-for="ServiceDate">@date5.TimeOfDay</label>
                    <input asp-for="ServiceDate" type="radio" id="dat5" value="@date5"><br>


                    <span asp-validation-for="ServiceDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="ReservationDate" class="form-control" value="@DateTime.Now" />

                    <span asp-validation-for="ReservationDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select asp-for="ServiceId" class="form-select">
                        <option selected disabled>Pick</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                    </select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="ServiceId" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </form>
```

I need to give every single date an ID because here is a loop that will disable particular radio button

```
@foreach (Reservation item in ListOfDates)
        {
            <a>@item.ServiceDate.Hour</a>
            if (@item.ServiceDate.Hour == 10)
            {
                <a>
                    <script>
                        document.getElementById("dat1").disabled = true;
                    </script>
                </a>
            }

            if (@item.ServiceDate.Hour == 10 && item.ServiceDate.Minute == 30)
            {
                <a>
                    <script>
                        document.getElementById("dat2").disabled = true;
                    </script>
                </a>
            }
            if (@item.ServiceDate.Hour == 11)
            {
                <a>
                    <script>
                        document.getElementById("dat3").disabled = true;
                    </script>
                </a>
            }
            if (@item.ServiceDate.Hour == 11 && item.ServiceDate.Minute == 30)
            {
                <a>
                    <script>
                        document.getElementById("dat4").disabled = true;
                    </script>
                </a>
            }
            if (@item.ServiceDate.Hour == 12)
            {
                <a>
                    <script>
                        document.getElementById("dat5").disabled = true;
                    </script>
                </a>
            }
            if (@item.ServiceDate.Hour == 12 && item.ServiceDate.Minute == 30)
            {
                <a>
                    <script>
                        document.getElementById("dat6").disabled = true;
                    </script>
                </a>
            }
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any option to disable these radio buttons in controller? Any tips for make this code clearer will be appreciated.

Comment: Any time you look at code where you've written `variable1, variable2, variable3...` that's candidate for making `variable` an array. Consider that an array is a way of making N variables with a name that is programmatically able to be varied. Instead of `variable1, variable2, variable3` it's `variable[0], variable[1], variable[2]`, the thing in square brackets being capable of being another variable..

Comment: One of the major time saving notions behind Razor follows on from this; you don't have to create the entire markup as you have done; you can use a loop with a segment of markup inside it and the loop will run N times producing slightly altered markup on each pass. A considerably majority of the markup you've put into the question is repeated with very little variation beyond something that can be programmatically described such as strings like dat1, dat2 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fairly easy to generate html in a loop. But rather than giving each radio button a number, I'd generate the id directly from the time. However I would disable each radio button in the HTML rather than generating javascript.

```cs
var now = DateTime.Now.Date;
var booked = ListOfDates
    .Select(r => r.ServiceDate)
    .ToHashSet();

for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    var dateValue = now + TimeSpan.FromHours(10 + i*0.5f);
    <label asp-for="ServiceDate">@dateValue.TimeOfDay</label>
    <input asp-for="ServiceDate" type="radio" id="dat@dateValue.ToString("hhMM")" value="@dateValue" disabled="@(booked.Contains(dateValue) ? "true" : null)"><br>
}
```